# how to stop template being created in a specific condition

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, datatrigger

I currently have a list of categories. For each category a template is created with an expander and datagrid which will display a list of items associated with the category. 
My problem is that if there are no items for a category, i don't want the template to be created for that category.
Currently i can get the template to hide, but its leaving a gap where the template has been made.

```
<StackPanel Name="CatagoryPanel" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CategoryList}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Expander />
                        <DataGrid />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Have to tried to set the Visibility as Collapsed???

Comment: Side note: I think you forgot a panel (e.g. StackPanel, see my answer below) around the Expander and DataGrid. I don't think DataTemplate can have two visual elements.

Comment: yes you are correct, i have them inside of a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I discovered the ItemTemplateSelector property of the ItemsControl, which let you provide a different data template for each item in the ItemsControl, depends on some logic running in run time.

Similar to Setter, but more elegant.

First, define a class derived from DataTemplateSelector. The right place to do it is in the code behind *.cs file (as this is part of the View).

```
public class CategoryTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        Category category = item as MusicViewModel.Category;
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        string key = (category.Count) > 0 ? "Category" : "EmptyCategory";
        DataTemplate dt = element.FindResource(key) as DataTemplate;

        return dt;
    }
}
```

Next within your stack panel, define the two data templates as resources, as well as the selector:

```
<StackPanel Name="CatagoryPanel" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EmptyCategory">
            <StackPanel><Expander /><DataGrid /></StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Category">
            <Expander />
        </DataTemplate>                
        <gms:CategoryTemplateSelector x:Key="selector" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <!-- now, define the actual ItemsControl: -->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}" />

</StackPanel>
```

Personally, I find this approach cleaner than the triggers, although logically they are very similar.

Hope this helped.